# Conditional compilation in database project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, conditional-compilation

I have a vs 2010 database project with two postdeployment scripts (InitData and TestData). I want to execute TestData only if DEBUG compilation constant exists, so Script.PostDeployment.sql script would look something like this:

```
:r .\InitData.sql
#if DEBUG
:r .\TestData.sql
#endif
```

But doing that I get a compilation error `Incorrect syntax near '#if'` , is there any way to achieve this?